# Residual Acf plot---autocorrelations always significant

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, residuals, stationarity, acf-pacf

I have a time series and I feel confident it is a stationery process after detrending it and deseasonalize it. It looks to have constant mean and variance and also satisfies the ADF test. I fitted multiply arima models and checked residuals however my Acf of the residuals does not appear to be white noise due to the fact there always appears to be at least one significant autocorrelation in the first 14 lags.

Would there be any reason for this as I have not come across it before?